# defined variable in let changed when function called twice

Tags: scheme, racket

Consider the following code:

```
(define f2!
  (let([n 0])
    (lambda()
      (set! n (add1 n))
      n)))
(f2!)
(f2!)
```

I would expect the output to be `1 1`, since every time we call `f2!`, `n` will be redefined to 0.

But the output is: `1 2`. Why is that?

Comment: I think `n` is bound in the local scope of the closure, but I'm not fluent in scheme :D

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more :DDDD

Comment: You return a closure that uses side-effects to change thr value of `n`. It is not initialized other than the one time when it is bound to the closure's scope.

Comment: This is not really an answer, but for your own edification, I’d suggest you ponder the following question: *why* do you believe `n` will be redefined to `0` every time `f2!` is called?

Comment: @AlexGoft too bad you deleted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52043806/find-number-of-lines-containing-a-word-in-each-file it's a valid question. The ansewr is: `grep '//' * | sed 's/:.*//' | uniq -c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let` is a syntactic sugar for an applied lambda, so it might be easier for you to see the reason for this using the expended form for let:
`(define f2! 
   ((lambda (n) 
        (lambda () (set! n (add1 n)) n)) 
   0))`

So when you define `f2!`, you **apply** a lambda (2nd line) while binding its parameter, `n`, to the scheme object `0` (4th line). The definition of `f2!` is the result of that application, another lambda object.
That internal lambda has an environment which contains the parameters of the first lambda (namely `n`). Not a copy of those parameters, but and actual reference to them, so when you apply that internal lambda and `set!` the value of `n`, you're setting the value of the referenced `n` as was bound when you first defined `f2!`.

TL;DR, you defined `f2!` once, at which point you bound `n`, and from that point on you're getting and setting that same `n`.

Answer (score 2):

You have made a function that is closed over a variable. In short this is a poor mans OO.

When you call `f1!` the same free binding `n` (instance variable) will be mutated and returned. You have created a counter.

You can do the same in many languages since most of them are lexical. eg. JS:

```js
const fBang = (() => {
  let n = 0;
  return () => ++n;
})();

console.log(fBang()); // prints 1
console.log(fBang()); // prints 2
```